# Azure log analytics severity level as string

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-log-analytics

Currently in azure application insights we see under severityLevel the number of ther severity level and not the text like information, error,... Is it possible to show the severityLevel as a string.

[image]

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [
    "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
],
"MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
},
"WriteTo": [
    {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
            "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
            "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
            "instrumentationKey": "key"
        }
    }
],
"Enrich": [
    "FromLogContext"
],
"Properties": {
    "Application": "Sample"
}
}
```

Comment: The Azure Portal will always show it as a number. The only thing I can think of is to log the text representation as a custom property or extend your kusto queries with the text based value.

Comment: Hi, Peter thanks for your reply. How could extending the kusto queries with the text based value could look like?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ad hoc function, using [let](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22QMU/DQAyF90j5D0%20ZcqgiZGABdQIGJMRSBEPV4Uic9NDlLvIZRKH8d5y2S6R6sa1nP39yVWFlh9ETegrEVlwMl3iOgtGyIHaQLSFF/zkpeeZJIGwbSlhisELsrHc/VLINPcGh4zighkTUV0hCozZ7jBw/qBEk%20tIN2T1p9uog0QWZdtvy2pgFXtxASRRINdvHo2Iu6taY2zyrFPZEotbKl7AlpiNVT7I6ud9TatiNh7klytnRGz1o8uw3z6DR7oIdXFOui1fi95ioWKB4DF3k4fCKqX2zHFzop/KBOfJU3Kmfa6wvNmY9s9/k2Z%20SHl%20UZ3vQt1BocR7tPPMc2PwDUdan6KMBAAA=) statement

```
// Sample generation. Not part of the solution
let traces = materialize(range i from 1 to 10 step 1 | project severityLevel = toint(rand(5)), Timestamp = ago(rand()*1d));
// Solution starts here
let getSeverityDescription = (severityLevel:int)
{
    dynamic(["Verbose", "Information", "Warning", "Error", "Critical"])[severityLevel]
};
traces
| extend SeverityDescription = getSeverityDescription(severityLevel)
```

| severityLevel | Timestamp | SeverityDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-06-29T11:56:30.3936027Z | Error |
| 4 | 2022-06-29T15:08:45.0941469Z | Critical |
| 4 | 2022-06-30T03:02:29.1658275Z | Critical |
| 1 | 2022-06-30T03:29:22.4724933Z | Information |
| 0 | 2022-06-30T04:01:15.7748102Z | Verbose |
| 0 | 2022-06-30T04:37:39.740977Z | Verbose |
| 2 | 2022-06-30T05:13:04.734582Z | Warning |
| 2 | 2022-06-30T07:32:01.9569582Z | Warning |
| 2 | 2022-06-30T07:41:46.3364296Z | Warning |
| 1 | 2022-06-30T09:42:22.5852665Z | Information |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22QMU/DQAyF90j5D0%20ZcqgiZGABdQIGJMRSBEPV4Uic9NDlLvIZRKH8d5y2S6R6sa1nP39yVWFlh9ETegrEVlwMl3iOgtGyIHaQLSFF/zkpeeZJIGwbSlhisELsrHc/VLINPcGh4zighkTUV0hCozZ7jBw/qBEk%20tIN2T1p9uog0QWZdtvy2pgFXtxASRRINdvHo2Iu6taY2zyrFPZEotbKl7AlpiNVT7I6ud9TatiNh7klytnRGz1o8uw3z6DR7oIdXFOui1fi95ioWKB4DF3k4fCKqX2zHFzop/KBOfJU3Kmfa6wvNmY9s9/k2Z%20SHl%20UZ3vQt1BocR7tPPMc2PwDUdan6KMBAAA=)

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple.

```
traces
| extend SeverityLevel = case(severityLevel == 1, "Information",severityLevel == 2, "Warning",severityLevel == 3, "Error", tostring(severityLevel)), FromDate=ago(30d) 
| where (timestamp >= FromDate)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The severity level is an enum, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.severitylevel?view=azure-dotnet):

Critical    4
Critical severity level.

Error   3
Error severity level.

Information 1
Information severity level.

Verbose 0
Verbose severity level.

Warning 2
Warning severity level.

We can use this to create a kusto query:

```
let severities = datatable(severityLevel:int, severity:string)
[
   0, "Verbose",
   1, "Information",
   2, "Warning",
   3, "Error",
   4, "Critical",
];
traces
| join severities on severityLevel
| project timestamp, message, severity
```